# Killing all other activities from a firestore snapshot listener in previous activity

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Snapshot listener listening to changes on Firestore. If the timestamp does not match, I want other activities to be killed to return to the login page (MainActivity).

Is there a way to kill current activity to go back to MainActivity (The first activity) which is the login activity?

All other question and solution I've searched for only give you the solution to kill previous activities. My question is, how do I kill current activity from a listener that is still running from previous activity?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution : -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CloseAllViewsDemo.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// This flag ensures all activities on top of the CloseAllViewsDemo are cleared.
                context.startActivity(intent);
                // To finish current activity
                finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put 
    this.finish()
after intent.
This will kill the current activity and wont return when back button is pressed.